# Material angular (tabs), set label background

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need today to work with angular Tabs (angular materials). I want to set the background of my md-tab-label(s) depending on the hosts collect status of the day.

[image: Screen of a beauty-full tab bar]

For example here I need to have the first tab label background as green. Know the expected color is not the problem, I just need your help to set the color into the CTP file (I think).

Something like this :

```
<md-tab-label backgroundColor="{{dayData.color}}">
    {{dayData.date}}
</md-tab-label>
```

Thanks a lot for any proposal <3

Comment: what comes from the dayData.color? is the actual css color name? if it is you could just add the style attribute there instead of placing that backgroundColor attribute.

Comment: Hi @Zorkind, my controller JS send the data to the .CTP, dayData.color can be "green" or "red", i just dont know where to put this then :/

Comment: Ok, so you could just change that attribute backgroundColor to something like style="background-color: {{dayData.color}}"

Comment: Nice try, it didn't works :/
I think Angular material have a special syntax for this special case, but i didn't have it :'(

Comment: Yeah it translates the directive into divs and whatnot.

Comment: I see you can use ng-template to make a complex Label, that you can make a custom box for your label, with css and all, but it wont get the entire area of the label, since it generates it's css classes on the fly, it's really troublesome to mess around with it.

Comment: Take a look at this, see if you can work with it somehow https://angular-w3svta.stackblitz.io

Comment: It looks like really nice, I will try it !

Comment: You can try binding it via `[style.backgroundColor]="dayData.color"`